# multiple select values error

Tags: php, javascript, html-select

I have a form that allows the user to select up to X amount of options from a multi-select field.  If the user selects an item greater than the X items it prompts and de-selects the last selected item.

There is an issue when the warning message has been thrown by a previous multi-select.

The form have 4 mult-selects, so if its thrown on the  third mult-select or the max number has already been reached by a previous mult-select it will throw the error for the next multi-select regardless of whether the user chooses the correct number.

Here is a code snippet.  The rest of the selects on the page are built the same way but use different names:

```
<select multiple name="seasons[]" size="6" id="seasons" onChange="countSelected(this,5)">
<option value=0>Hold CTRL to select more than one</option>
<?
  $ftw = mysql_query("SELECT s.seasonId, s.type FROM seasons s ORDER BY s.seasonId ASC");
  while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($ftw)) {
     $queried = mysql_query("SELECT seasonId FROM selectedSeason where seasonId = '$line[0]' AND id = '$objItem->itemId'");
      if(mysql_fetch_row($queried))
         echo "<option selected value=\"$line[0]\">". $line[1] ."</option>";
      else 
         echo "<option value=\"$line[0]\">". $line[1] ."</option>";
   }
?>
</select>
```

Here is the javascript to warn:

```
var selectedOptions = [];

function countSelected(select,maxNumber){
   for(var i=0; i<select.options.length; i++){
     if(select.options[i].selected && !new RegExp(i,'g').test(selectedOptions.toString())){
        selectedOptions.push(i);
     }

     if(!select.options[i].selected && new RegExp(i,'g').test(selectedOptions.toString())){
      selectedOptions = selectedOptions.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
       for(var j=0; j<selectedOptions.length; j++){
         if(selectedOptions[j] == i){
            selectedOptions.splice(j,1);
         }
       }
     }

     if(selectedOptions.length > maxNumber){
      var throwAlert = true;
        select.options[i].selected = false;
        selectedOptions.pop();
     }
   }

     if(throwAlert == true){
        alert('You may only choose '+maxNumber+' options!!');
        document.body.focus();
     }
}
```

seasons needs to be seasons[] so it can post multiple values to PHP. I have no issue posting or retrieving data just with the javascript.  The error occurs in IE, FF, and Safari but not Chrome...alas.

Any ideas would be invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

i guess u need to make the selectedOptions into a multidimensional array something on the lines

```
selectedOptions[0][0] /// indicating to first select box option 1
selectedOptions[0][1] /// indicating to first select box option 2
```

something on those lines should work.

Edit:
if you want to do it the quick and dirty way have selectedOptions1[] selectedOptions2[] etc and use an if else statement to work with the correct array at the start of the js function.